# Slow FluentValidation performance .net 6?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I want to use FluentValidation in our production site and wants to know what the performance could be. So I wrote a fairly simple test, to my surprise, FluentValidation seems to be really poor. I am wondering maybe my test is not correct? If the test is unfortunately correct, is there anyway to improve the performance?
The result in (ms):
[image]
My test:

```
    public class TestItem
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
        public string Value3 { get; set; }
        public string Value4 { get; set; }
        public string Value5 { get; set; }
        public string Value6 { get; set; }
        public string Value7 { get; set; }
        public string Value8 { get; set; }
        public string Value9 { get; set; }
        public string Value10 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemValidator : AbstractValidator<TestItem>
    {
        public ItemValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Value1).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value2).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value3).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value4).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value5).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value6).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value7).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value8).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value9).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Value10).NotEmpty();

        }
    }
    public class StupidValidator
    {
        public void Validate(TestItem item)
        {
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value1);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value2);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value3);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value4);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value5);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value6);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value7);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value8);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value9);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value10);
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ItemValidator val = new ItemValidator();
            StupidValidator stupidValidator= new StupidValidator();

            List<TestItem> items = new List<TestItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                items.Add(new TestItem());
            }

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                val.Validate(items[i]);
            }


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("fluentValidation uses:"+sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
            sw.Restart();

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                stupidValidator.Validate(items[i]);
            }


            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Stupid one uses:" + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**Update 1:**
If I create the fluent validator in this way, the validation takes around 130ms, still much slower than the stupid one, but better than before.

```
    public class ItemValidator : AbstractValidator<TestItem>
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext<TestItem> context)
        {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult()
            {

            };
            var item= context.InstanceToValidate;
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value1);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value2);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value3);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value4);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value5);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value6);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value7);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value8);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value9);
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value10);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that StupidValidator isn't doing anything because it just discards the resulting boolean that string.IsNullOrEmpty() returns. I'd be surprised if the optimizer didn't discard all those calls in a release build.